How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln(\sin x) \ln(\cos x)}{\tan(2x)} \sin(2x) \, dx $

Problem statement

How to evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln(\sin x) \ln(\cos x)}{\tan(2x)} \sin(2x) \, dx
$$

My attempt

Consider the integral:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln(\sin x) \ln(\cos x)}{\tan(2x)} \sin(2x) \, dx
$$
We know that:
$$
\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)
$$
$$
\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)
$$
Substituting, we have:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln(\sin x) \ln(\cos x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)} \left(1 - 2\sin^2(x)\right) dx
$$
Recall that:
$
\tan(2x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}
$
Let $\sin(x) = p$. Then $dp = \cos(x) \, dx$, and $dx = \frac{dp}{\cos(x)}$.
So, the integral becomes:
$$
J = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\ln(p) \ln\left(\sqrt{1 - p^2}\right)}{2p\sqrt{1 - p^2}} \left(1 - p^2\right) \frac{dp}{\sqrt{1 - p^2}}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(1 - p^2) \ln(p) \left(1 - 2p^2\right)\right)}{p(1 - p^2)} \, dp
$$
Can someone help evaluate the last integral?

I think you made a mistake applying the double angle formulas in the integral.

The denominator is $\tan(2x)$ but not $\cos(2x)$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \quad  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln (\sin x) \ln (\cos x)}{\tan (2 x)} \sin (2 x) d x \\&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos (2 x) \ln (\sin x) \ln (\cos x) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\sin x) \ln (\cos x) d(\sin (2 x)) \\
& =\frac{1}{2}[\sin (2 x) \ln (\sin x) \ln (\cos x)]_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} -  \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin (2 x)\left[\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \ln (\cos x)-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \ln (\sin x)\right]dx\\
&=  \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos ^2 x \ln (\cos x) d x+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin ^2 x \ln (\sin x) dx\\ &=  \frac{1}{8} \ln 2-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1+\cos 2 x}{2} \ln (\cos x) d x  +\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1-\cos 2 x}{2} \ln (\sin x) d x\\&= \frac{1}{8} \ln 2+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\tan x) d x-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos (2 x) \ln (\cos x \sin x) d x\\
&=\frac{1}{8} \ln 2-\frac{G}{2}+\frac{1}{4}(1+\ln 2) \quad (\textrm{ via } \sin (2x)\mapsto x)
\end{aligned}
$$

Really great answer!!

Alternatively
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln(\sin x) \ln(\cos x)}{\tan2x} \sin2x\, dx\\
= &\ \frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} {\ln(\sin x) \ln(\cos x)}d\left(\sin 2x\right)\\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac18\ln^2 2
+\frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\tan x)dx
+\frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos2x\ln\frac{\sin2x}2\ dx\\
=&\ \frac18\ln^2 2-\frac12G+\frac14(\ln2+1)
\end{align}

Wow, impressive, + 1!

As always fantastic.
